# Pylance: Ignore type warnings from specific package

Tags: python, pylance

A specific package (in my case, `dash`) is triggering lots of false warnings because of its bad type annotations.

Is there a way to keep using pylance to check my types for everything else, but ignore the warnings that arise when I call anything of the form `dash.Callable()`?